# JavaScript, html5: how to dynamically create a Vignette effect?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, effects, vignette

So what I need is simple: user presses something, user sees Vignette effect on new div on top of all page (with page size) alike  [image: chrome set up page]

Is it possible with some html5 canvas art? And how to do such thing?

Comment: If you're really talking about HTML5-capable browsers, you could probably do this without needing a canvas. You'd just need a rounded-corner box (or two) with some widely-blurred box shadow(s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, this is *exactly* how Chrome's settings page is doing it: http://jsfiddle.net/JRGHM/

```
.overlay {
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s opacity;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.5),
                                      rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.5) 35%,
                                      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7));
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  left: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 130px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

As you can see, the important part is the gradient.

You can make that code work in all browsers that support CSS3 gradients by adding the appropriate gradient syntax: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients

Comment: Yes, it can. That's what I did, but once I saw how it was doing it and that it was called `.overlay`, I figured it would be clearer to take it from the source.

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to note that in case anyone is wondering how to find that out.

Comment: @Kabumbus: Looks good! Here's a version with the `98%`s fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/XHAbV/2/